# Spring Boot many to many relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating an Api Rest with Spring Boot.

I have two tables (books) and (authors) that share a many-to-many relationship (books_authors).

How do I insert a record in the table (author_books), if the author does not exist, taking into account that in the same form where the books are created there is a button to create new authors?

How do I send a Json of the book to be created, where the authors and author that does not exist are nested, without knowing the id of the book to which it belongs?

Comment: Why you want the insert book record when there is no related author record in join table? You can form relationship when both entity exists. Like Create Book, When Author is added, get the Book object and update the relationship.

Comment: I am a beginner in this Spring Boot and Java, but I saw that with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` I can do

Comment: cascade = CascadeType.ALL will work only when all the objects are present to cascade the save operation, i will not add partial entry in join table